One colorbar for several contour plots
I generated three plots using:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(12,4))
X,Y=np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

P1=ax[0].contourf(X,Y,A) 
ax[0].set_title('Plot A')
P2=ax[1].contourf(X,Y,B)
ax[1].set_title('Plot B')
P3=ax[2].contourf(X,Y,C)
ax[2].set_title('Plot C')

How can I add one colorbar for all subplots?

I see you have already accepted an answer using ImageGrid, but you could also just pass your array of axes from subplots to the colorbar call: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/multi_image.html#multiple-images-with-one-colorbar

You may want to look at Matplotlib's ImageGrid:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

x, y = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j]
z1 = np.sin(x**2 + y**2)
z2 = np.cos(x**2 + y**2)

cmap = "inferno"

fig = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(
    fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
    nrows_ncols=(1, 2),  # creates 1x2 grid of Axes
    axes_pad=0.2,  # pad between Axes in inch.
    cbar_mode="single"
)
grid[0].contourf(x, y, z1, cmap=cmap)
grid[1].contourf(x, y, z2, cmap=cmap)

norm = Normalize(vmin=min(z1.min(), z2.min()), vmax=max(z1.max(), z2.max()))
cb2 = grid[1].cax.colorbar(
    ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),
    label = "z value"
)
plt.show()



Adapting @gboffi's answer, we can also pass explicit levels to keep the colors aligned between the three plots and their colorbar.  This way, we can just use the scalarmappable that is returned from contourf.  Note also that we see the level boundaries in the colorbar instead of the smooth gradient shown in @gboffi's first colorbar.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(range(21), range(16))
z0 = x/10+y/5 # max z0 =  5
z1 = z0 + x/4 # max z1 = 10
z2 = x/10*y/5 # max z2 =  6

zmin = min(z.min() for z in (z0, z1, z2))
zmax = max(z.max() for z in (z0, z1, z2))
levels = np.linspace(zmin,zmax,11)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10,3), layout='constrained')
axs[0].contourf(x, y, z0, levels=levels, cmap='plasma')
axs[1].contourf(x, y, z1, levels=levels, cmap='plasma')
cf = axs[2].contourf(x, y, z2, levels=levels, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar(cf, ax=axs)

plt.show()



This is the correct answer.  The accepted answer is mildly discouraged.

I second Jody's comment.


First you have to use the same color scale for all the filled contour plots, and this can be solved using plt.Normalize(vmin, vmax, ...) that returns a linear transformation from the interval (vmin, vmax) to (0, 1), and using the same transformation for all the plots.
You can specify that plt.colorbar steals space from an Axes or from an iterable of Axes, the syntax is colorbar(..., ax=ax) or colorbar(..., ax=axs), and this remark addresses where the colorbar is placed and how the Figure Axes are shrinked.
The final problem is is what you want to place inside the colorbar, usually you use the Scalar Mappable that is returned from your contourf but here you have three different plots... so you can build an ad hoc SM using matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable, specifying the normalization function (the one you used in all the contourf) and possibly a colormap, if you have not used the default one in the plots.
You can see all of the above in the code below.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(range(21), range(16))
z0 = x/10+y/5 # max z0 =  5
z1 = z0 + x/4 # max z1 = 10
z2 = x/10*y/5 # max z2 =  6
zmin = min(z.min() for z in (z0, z1, z2))
zmax = max(z.max() for z in (z0, z1, z2))
norm = plt.Normalize(zmin, zmax)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(10,3), layout='constrained')
axs[0].contourf(x, y, z0, norm=norm, cmap='plasma')
axs[1].contourf(x, y, z1, norm=norm, cmap='plasma')
axs[2].contourf(x, y, z2, norm=norm, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='plasma'), ax=axs)


Each contourf returns a ScalarMappable, so one is tempted to use one of those to instantiate the colorbar, but in this case the range of the colorbar goes from min(z_i) to max(z_i), not what we desire. E.g., using ax[2].contourf(x, y, z2, ...) as our ScalarMappable we have


Also note that the return value of contourf is a scalarmappable, so you can just choose one of those three instead of creating an extra one for the colorbar.

@RuthC I mentioned that contourf returns a Scalar Mappable , that usually you use to create the Color Bar. Prompted by your comment, I tried the equivalent of plt.colorbar(ax[2].contourf(...)) but the colorbar ran from 0 to 6.4, that is the max value of z2 so my gut feeling that it was necessary a new SM has been confirmed.

@RuthC I have edited my answer to address your comment, thank you.

Ah yes, you are right.  I had assumed that colorbar's range would be defined by the norm.  I usually pass explicit levels, instead of a norm and in that case it works as I expected.  I will post an extra answer with that.
